# Opentok Javascript: On self session/connection disconnect?

Tags: opentok

Opentok Javascript: On self session/connection disconnect?
I tried all the possible events, following code logs into the console when other deivces disconnects, but it never logs anything when it, itself, disconnects. Please point toward the even which is fired when the session is disconnected. I have tried `sessionDisconnect` as well without any luck.

```
this.session.on("connectionDestroyed", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The Session object dispatches [SessionDisconnectEvent](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/SessionDisconnectEvent.html) object when a session has disconnected. You mentioned that you tried, `sessionDisconnect`, but the event is actually `sessionDisconnected`.

You can listen to the event as such:

```
this.session.on("sessionDisconnected", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```

The `connectionDestroyed` event is dispatched when other connections leave the session.

Comment: I just found the same in documentation right after asking the question.